# How do I use a custom domain in local_applicationIdUris in env.default.json file in Teams App development

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have updated my AAD App Registration Api endpoint to point to my custom domain (api://{customdomain}/{clientid}). However when I update same in my local_applicationIdUris variable in env.default.json file and build the application, the value copied into default.userdata changes to api://localhost/{clientid}.
I would like to use the same app registration for local development and testing on Azure deployment but this poses a challenge as Azure App registration requires a valid domain name

Comment: Could you please confirm if the answer provided helps?

Answer (score 0):

To use the same app registration for local development and testing on Azure deployment, please map your custom domain to your local server.

Steps to map your custom domain to your local server :

1. Add  the IP address of your server  and custom domain in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
2. Add a A record in your Domain Registrar with your custom domain and IP address of your local server.